# Asynchronous Response to an ajax call in Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

When performing a heavy duty task, like removing all data from a database by tables or similar, is it possible to return a partial response of an ajax request to indicate current status of the task?

For example if I had 5 tables in a database and run queries to delete data from those tables one by one, is it possible to send a status message after deleting data from each table by json or some other way?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried sending response by echo, but  it returns all the response after execution of the script, not one by one.

Comment: you can do so using redis and socket io

Comment: either runs the script in parts like delete 100 records then return then again 100 records and return, because when you execute query , it will only return when whole query is executed or any error occured

Comment: did you tried to use sleep(secunds) php function when every table has cleared?

Comment: Yes, it didnt work @DejavuGuy

Comment: You can't return ajax incrementally, the way ajax works is when the response is complete and finished, it replaces the innerHTML of an element with the response from the page. **It's a one shot deal that doesn't happen incrementally.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server can't respond you a `partial` response at least you were working with sockets or something like that which is not the case because you're using ajax.